# Вопрос касаемо строки из языка паскаль

Tags: pascal

```
for i:= to n do
begin
    a[i]:= randon(100)-50;
    if (a[i]or (a[i]30) a[i]:=0;
    write(a[i],' ');
end;
```

(это учебное задание)
я хочу разобраться со строкой "if (a[i]or (a[i]30) a[i]:=0;" сижу уже сколько времени и не могу понять, что именно она должна делать(программа изначально идет с кучей опечаток).

Answer (score 0):

Невозможно определить, что там было.

Хотите рабочий вариант - делайте любое условие от фонаря, например

```
 if (a[i] < -30) or (a[i] > 30) then
    a[i]:=0;
```

Comment: в данном коде кучча ошибок и моя задача перевести его на пайтон с учетом что не паскаль не пайтон я не помню :) а в исходном варианте на паскале сделано куча ошибок, хз спецально или нет, вот я и спрашиваю какой смысл имеет данная строка что бы понять как перевести ее на питон

Comment: Смысл - некоторые значения a[i] обнуляются. Какие именно условия обнуления - ХЗ

Comment: могу скинуть полный код если интересно

Comment: Нет, неинтересно. Возможный вариант для кода из вопроса я привел, точно угадать невозможно